# BigQuery union schema based on field location and not name

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to run a BigQuery union query and have the schema depend on field name and not field location. The result for the following query isn't intuitive, where the fields are transposed since their order is different in the underlying tables.

```
with table1 as (
  select 
    '1' as field_1,
    '2' as field_2
),

table2 as (
  select 
    '2' as field_2,
    '1' as field_1
)


select * from table1
union all 
select * from table2
```

Query Result
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the columns by name in the appropriate order, regardless of how the table is defined:

```
SELECT
  field_1,
  field_2
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT
  field_1,
  field_2
FROM table2
```

It would probably be best just to reorder the columns in the underlying table, though:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE table2 AS
SELECT
  field_1,
  field_2
FROM table2
```

Then you have a consistent column order.

Comment: The tables here were just and example. I want to union using "select *" and the real underlying tables have a massive nested schema, so re-ordering them is quite a pain. Why is union based on column location and not on column name?

Comment: This is how unions work in all major query engines, not just BigQuery. Columns are associated by position per the SQL standard.